# Let $E_c:=\{x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \ge c\}$ Prove that $\int_{E_c}f\,dm \ge c\cdot m(E_c)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\ge 0$ be a measurable real-valued function defined on $\mathbb R$.
For each $c>0$, Let $E_c:=\{x \in\mathbb R :f(x)\ge c \}$. Prove that \

$$\int_{E_c}f\,dm\ge c \cdot m(E_c).$$

My idea is to construct a sequence of simple functions approximation of $f$\

$\Phi_n=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\chi_{E_i}$.
since we are integrating over  $E_c:=\{x \in\mathbb R :f(x)\ge c \}$,   I will let  $a_i \ge c \quad \forall a_i $ \

By definition,
$\int_{E_c}f\,dm= \sup\left\{\int_{E_C}\Phi \, dm, \Phi\le f \right\}$ \and

$\int_{E_C}\Phi \, dm  =\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \cdot m(E_i)$. So  In this case  $E_c=\bigcup E_i$ \

But

$$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \cdot m(E_i) \color{red}{\ge} \sum_{i=1}^N c\cdot m(E_i) = c \sum_{i=1}^N m(E_i) \text{ since } a_i \ge c \quad \forall a_i $$

by additivity of measure \

$c\sum_{i=1}^N m(E_i)=c\cdot m\left(\bigcup E_i\right)=c\cdot m(E_c)$
but I feel something is off.

Can you please help me out. thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should know that if $f  \ge  g,$ then $\int f \ge \int g.$ Do you see how this could help you out?

Comment: Yes,it helps a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things: note that $f(x)\geq c\chi_{E_c}(x)$ for all $x\in E_c$ by the definition of $E_c$. So what do you get if you integrate both sides of this inequality?

Comment: If $f(x)\ge c\chi_{E_c}(x)$ for all $ x \in R $ then $\int f(x)dm \ge \int c\chi_{E_c}(x)dm $

Comment: Exactly. And the right-hand side is just $cm(E_c)$.

Comment: Oh okay , I see. It looks clearer now. thank you very much.